# Rails if conditional in controller error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement

I'm wondering how can I print on the index of my project only the rooms with the :is_available column or the rooms table with the :true value (is boolean).

I can't figure out how to achieve this (Sorry but I'm new with Rails). Any advice will be very appreciate!

I've this error with my current code:

"ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in RoomsController#home 
Couldn't find Room without an ID"

Here is my rooms_controller code:

```
class RoomsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :get_room, only: [:index, :home]

  def index

  end


  def show
    @room = Room.find(params[:id])
  end


  def home
    if params[:set_locale]
        redirect_to root_url(locale: params[:set_locale])
    else

        puts @rooms if Room.all(params[:is_available => :true])
    end
  end



  def get_room
    @rooms = Room.all
  end


end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have got `@rooms = Room.all`, you just need to precise your query (from all to your `is_available` restriction).

```
  def home
    if params[:set_locale]
        redirect_to root_url(locale: params[:set_locale])
    else
        puts @rooms.where(is_available: true)
    end
  end
```

Also, you should avoid using `puts` in your controller logic. Either pass variable to the view (you can change `@rooms` value or create new variable `@available_rooms`), `respond_with` it or log it using `Rails.logger` if you use puts as a debugging solution.

Comment: Thanks r-k i used the @available_rooms = @rooms.where(is_available: true), passing the new variable to the home view and it solve my issue. I think it's a cleaner solution. I appreciate a lot your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
  def index    
  end

  def home
    if params[:set_locale]
      redirect_to root_url(locale: params[:set_locale])
    elsif params[:is_available]
      puts @rooms 
    end
  end

  def get_room
    @rooms = Room.where(is_available: true)
  end
```

Using puts in controller - not a good idea.Use view to show the data.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues you may have:

---

**Routes**

Your `index` method looks empty. I presume you're using "home" as a substitute

In this case, you have to know what type of action this is - a `member` or `collection` action? The reason this is important is that when you define your `routes`, you have to ensure you define the route in the right way. For your `home` route, I'd have done this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :rooms do 
    get "home", action: "home"
end
```

---

**Scopes**

You can use a [`scope`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) to bring back all the values with `:is_available` present. This lives in the model like this:

```
#app/models/room.rb
Class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :is_available?, -> { where(is_available: true) }
end
```

This will allow you to call

```
@room = Room.is_available?
```

---

**Code**

Although you've not given us any context of the error (when it happens, what you do to make it happen), this is what I would do to help fix it:

```
  #app/controllers/rooms_controller.rb
  def home
    if params[:set_locale]
        redirect_to root_url(locale: params[:set_locale])
    else
        puts Room.is_available?
    end
  end
```

This may change depending the params you send & how you send them

Comment: Thanks Joe Hilton but I've my index empty but there is the "get_room" def filtering at beginning, and my config/routes.rb the root_path is rooms#home. I just solved it with the r-k suggestion but your solution made me understand how to implement the scope in the models. I appreciate your answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

```
def home
    if params[:set_locale]
        redirect_to root_url(locale: params[:set_locale])
    else

        puts @rooms if params[:is_available] && Room.where(is_available: true)
    end
  end
```

should work.

Comment: Ok, now the index page prints all the rooms even if the :is_available is set to true or not.